# JQuery Ajax jqxhr how to intercept OnReadyStateChange?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to implement some kind of "comet" with this code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8;");
print ob_get_level ();
ob_end_flush(); //ends the automatic ob started by PHP
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  $randSlp=rand(1,3);
  echo "Sleeping for ".$randSlp." second. ";
  flush();
  sleep(1);
  var_dump( ob_get_level());
}
?>
```

But this doesn't send the `200 OK` until it finishes.

I'd like to get it while loading and do something with `Jquery`, so I think the `readyState` will be 3.

But how can I make this if `JQuery jqxhr` object doesn't implement the `onReadyStateChange`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you refered http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ It have complete information on jQuery Ajax handling.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy in Jquery No onreadystatechange mechanism is provided, however, since done, fail, always, and statusCode cover all conceivable requirements.

by documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

so you should use XMLHttpRequest see http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

Comment: That is a quote from the page, so you should enclose it in quotation marks: "No onreadystatechange mechanism is provided, however, since done, fail, always, and statusCode cover all conceivable requirements." That's literally the jquery.ajax documentation.

Answer (score 0):

@javierZanetti quoted "No onreadystatechange mechanism is provided, however, since done, fail, always, and statusCode cover all conceivable requirements." from https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Therefore I think you would use the "always" mechanism which will be triggered while it's loading, whether it will eventually fail or succeed.